# Corda: How to add custom validating code for every node on a particular transacting state in Corda

Tags: corda

In the Corda-example, if we want to add custom validating code, we can override checkTransaction() in the responder codes to make sure the IOU is above a certain threshold. This assumes that all responders are agreeable to that threshold.

What if we allow every lender to set their own threshold. In that case the threshold becomes a variable. To address this, I created a UI that directly publishes the threshold (an integer) to the database. However I am finding it hard to extract the value and passing it to a threshold variable in the flow code. Is there a better way? If this works, I can quarantine more variables and using the UI for individual nodes, I get to set custom parameters (into the database) used in the validation of the state in the Tx.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to provide a different implementation of the flow for each node. For example, if you had an `AcceptTxBasedOnThreshold` flow, you'd create several implementations:

- One `AcceptTxBasedOnThreshold` flow implementation for NodeA, which perhaps has a threshold of 10
- One `AcceptTxBasedOnThreshold` flow implementation for NodeB, which perhaps has a threshold of 20 instead
- And so on for any additional nodes...

You'd then create several CorDapps:

- The first CorDapp would include the shared state and contract definitions that everyone uses. You'd install this CorDapp on every node. This CorDapp wouldn't include any flow definitions
- You'd then create an additional CorDapp for each node:

  - A CorDapp with only NodeA's `AcceptTxBasedOnThreshold` flow. This CorDapp would only be installed by NodeA
  - A CorDapp with only NodeB's `AcceptTxBasedOnThreshold` flow. This CorDapp would only be installed by NodeB

Comment: how to make sure then that the parties are not running flow instructions which they are not qualified to run then if everyone could have custom flows (esp the issuance flow). How would the whitelisting work in this way? Do we need to hardcode into the contract code to check for specific legal entities for specific flows

Comment: People are allowed to have custom flows by design. Each participant owns their node and can control what flow code they install on it.